# How to make program shut itself after 3 wrong passwords in C++?

Tags: c++, loops

I need a program that after 1 wrong password it shows certain messege, after 2 wrong tries shows diffrent messege and after 3rd one it shut itself off. Of course after correct password it should turn the program on.

It has to contain do...while.

Here's the part of the code that should operate passwords (if there are any difficulties with language I can translate but it's just passwords and messeges to show):

```
int licznik = 0; // licznik => counter
string ha; // ha short hand for haslo => passowrd

cout << "Podaj haslo:" << endl; // Prodaj => to try, to pass
cin >> ha;
if (ha != "haslo" && licznik < 3)
    cout << "Haslo bledne, sprobuj jeszcze raz!" << endl;
    // blende => wrong
    // jeszcze => once
    // raz => again
else
    cout << "Haslo prawidlowe!";
    // prawidlowe => correct

do {
    licznik++;
    if (licznik <= 2)
        cout << "Ostatnia szansa!!!!!" << endl;
        // Ostatnia => final
        // szansa => chance
    else {
        exit(0);
    }
} while (ha == "haslo");
```

Comment: Note: "I can translate but it's just passwords and messeges" --> `licznik, ha` are neither passwords nor messages.

Comment: Maybe it should be `} while (ha != "haslo");` since you want to loop while the password is not equal to the target password. Although with that said you probably want a while loop instead of a do {} while () since if the user got it correctly the first time you don't want to enter the loop.

Comment: Variable names and text literals are important part of the source code self-documentation. For you, translating them to English would take 3 minutes; now think of a dozen of people who would each lose 5 minutes of their lives trying to figure out what you try to achieve in your code and another several dozens who could  have helped you, but were put off by the way you presented the code.  Each bug is related to meaning: it is where the code does sth. different from what the programmer think it really does.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite easy to achieve **even without** using statements **like `goto` or nested conditions** in a very simplified manner (read the comments for explanation):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    std::string password;
    int chances = 3;

    do {
        // Get the user input (could be multispaced)
        std::getline(std::cin, password);

        if (password == "haslo")
            break;

        // Conditioning the attempts
        if (chances != 0) {
            std::cout << "You have " << chances-- << " left\n";
            continue;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Password invalid.\n";
            return -1;
        }
    } while (true);

    std::cout << "Access granted.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Here's a sample test case:

```
rohanbari@genesis:~/stack$ ./a.out
hello
You have 3 left
there
You have 2 left
haslo
Access granted.
```

Comment: Good answer but one suggestion `if (password == "haslo")` is unnecessary. you can easily refactor your code and it will look neater and at the low level perform better. (Of course if you compiler does not optimize it)

Comment: I saw your earlier comment, dont get me wrong, just want to help you out, I think that your answer is in some way better than mine. (counting down for example, instead of going up like I did). In fact my had an extra if statement :(

Answer (score 1):

I am Slavic descent, but I cannot read polish thus it is hard for me to understand exactly what you mean, and what you want, but my best guess is that you wanted something like this:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    int licznik = 0;
    string ha;

    cout << "Enter password:" << endl;

    do {
        if (licznik > 2) {
            std::cout << "You entered password too many times";
            exit (0);
        } else if (licznik > 0) 
            cout << "You entered wrong password "  
                 << licznik <<  " times. Try again: "
                 << endl;

        cin >> ha;

        licznik++;
    } while (ha != "haslo");

    std::cout << "Success you are logged in" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It might be helpful for you to learn

Here I have use multiple `goto statement` within `if conditions` in do-while loop. Basically goto statement is an unconditional jump statement used for transferring the control of a program. you can also learn [goto statement](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/goto) here.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string pass; 
    int x = 0;
a:   // when two tries are left
b:   // when 1 try is left
    cout << "Enter password : " << ' ';
    cin >> pass;

    if (pass != "password" && x < 3)
    {
        cout << "Password incorrect\n";
        do
        {
            x++;
            if (x == 1)
            {
                cout << "please try again (2 try left)\n\n";
                goto a;
            }
            else
                if (x == 2)
                {
                    cout << "please try again (1 try left)\n\n";
                    goto b;

                }
                else
                    if (x == 3)
                    {
                        cout << "terminating\n\n";
                        exit(1);
                    }

        } while (x <= 3);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Password is correct\n\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Enter password :  World
Password incorrect
please try again (2 try left)
Enter password :  prom
Password incorrect
please try again (1 try left)
Enter password :  password
Password is correct
```

Comment: This could be simplified by using what @RohanBari did.

Comment: yeah I know , but it doesn't matter how you build your logic and code. I think everyone has their own coding style

Comment: Good point. :) I upvoted on yours and Rohan's answer, but extra if statements in C/C++ are translated into binary code, and sometimes they are optimized by compiler, but you do not want to depend on compiler, you want your code to compile as neatly as possible, on all compilers.